# ASP.NET MVC caching html with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing an ASP .NET WebAPI with client-side angular.js. As I need users to be ale to add navigable pages, I have created a NavBarCtrl with an associated partial view to allow for adding new pages into the nav-bar. When I rebuild then run my project in VS Community 2015, I get a (mostly) proper layout, though the styling from bootstrap does seem to be a bit off. [image: NavBar Partial after rebuild]

However, if I run the project again without rebuilding, I see the following:[image: NavBar Partial without rebuild]

Interestingly, the URL that appears directly after a rebuild is "http://localhost:32847/", whereas without a rebuild I see "http://localhost:32847/app/Views/PartialViews/NavigationBar.html".
Is there some sort of caching going on with angular that I am not aware of?

_ViewStart.cshtml:

```
@{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/execumatch")
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="execumatch">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="Execumatch"></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="NavBarCtrl" ng-include="navBarTemplate"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

NavigationBar.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" />
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="page in pages" class="navbar-link navbar-btn">
            <a href="{{page.url}}" >{{page.title}}</a>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil navbar-link" ng-click="edit" />
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove navbar-link" ng-click="delete" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <form name="pageCreate" ng-show="isCreating" novalidate ng-submit="createPage(newPage)">
                <input name="pagetitle" ng-model="newPage.title" placeholder="New Page" />
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" ng-click="createPage(newPage)" />
            </form>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button ng-click="startCreating()" class="navbar-link">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Additionally, I notice that the navbar does not quite look like a proper bootstrap navigation bar. I don't know if this is related to the previous problem or a separate one dealing with css in angular.

Comment: do you have any console errors ?

Comment: No errors in Visual Studio or in the browser.